# Как (какой командой) можно изменить дату определенного коммита на другую?

Tags: git, git-commit

Типа такой команды:

```
git commit --amend --no-edit --date='2019.01.01 21:00'
```

но чтобы можно было указать ID коммита. Я хочу изменить даты всех моих локальных коммитов, а не только последнего.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454734/how-can-one-change-the-timestamp-of-an-old-commit-in-git

Comment: Я бы там большими красными буквами выделил, что перепишется ВСЯ история после изменённого коммита

Comment: Спасибо. Пришел к тому, что нужно в git-bash (а у меня он на Windows) сделать всё по этому комментарию  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454734/how-can-one-change-the-timestamp-of-an-old-commit-in-git#comment87834212_454750], то есть прямо из командной строки git-bash запускать функцию. Но не знаю как это сделать.

Comment: функцию имеет смысл создавать, если вам надо регулярно менять даты коммитов. если это однократная операция — смысла в функции нет.

Answer (score 2):

например, можно воспользоваться командой `fitler-branch`.

если в коммите вам надо поменять только даты (их, между прочим две — «author date» и «commiter date»; чаще всего они совпадают, но могут и отличаться), то подойдёт опция `--env-filter команда`:

```
$ git filter-branch --env-filter 'if [ $GIT_COMMIT = "хэш" ]; \
then export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="дата" GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="дата"; fi'
```

- `хэш` — хэш коммита должен быть указан полностью, никаких сокращений
- `дата` — должна быть представлена в любом из форматов, понятных программе *git* (см. секцию "[date formats](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#_date_formats)" в `$ man git-commit`)

---

если вам надо установить одну и ту же дату (учтите, что под «датой» в данном случае подразумевается и *календарная дата* и *время*) для **всех** коммитов, то просто опустите условную конструкцию из предыдущей команды:

```
$ git filter-branch --env-filter 'export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="дата" GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="дата"'
```

---

если требются какие-то более сложные манипуляции с датами, то лучше задать отдельный **конкретный** вопрос по этому поводу.

Answer (score 1):

Установить текущую дату крайнего коммита

```
git commit --amend --no-edit --date=now
```

Comment: Эта команда уже есть в вопросе